# PHP is_dir function is too slow when comparing many large files

Tags: php, function, filesize

I have a directory with over 600 mp4 files in it and a few directories. I am trying to loop through the files and determine if the file is a directory or not and get the filesize.  The problem is that is_dir and filesize take WAY to long when getting this info for large files (>2GB).  Is there an efficient way to do this?  in my example code I have commented out filesize and is_dir and then I get the array back in a few seconds.  Otherwise it takes forever.

```
    $files=array();
    $directory=opendir($dir);
    while ($file = readdir($directory)) {
        if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != '$RECYCLE.BIN'){
                $rec=array(
                    'afile'=>"{$dir}/{$file}",
                    'name'=>$file
                );
                //if(is_dir($rec['afile'])){$rec['type']='dir';}
                //else{$rec['type']='file';}
                //$rec['size']=filesize($rec['afile']);
                $files[]=$rec;
            }
        }
    closedir($directory);
```

Comment: Are you using or could you use a database?

Comment: I probably wouldn't do this myself, but if the performance is a serious issue, you could consider making a shell call from php to `ls -l` and parsing the output for directories and file sizes.

Comment: This isn't a "this will solve your problem" but I've liked the things in http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php for working with the file system.

Comment: I tried ls -l and it had the same problem.  ls worked fine.

Comment: Hmm if `ls -l` is also very slow (tried also from the command line?) then your problem might run deeper than PHP. What type of filesystem is it? Is it mounted over NFS? USB?

Comment: For instance, running `ls -lR` recursively over 60GB of music and thousands files is nearly instantaneous for me on ext4, limited only by how fast the terminal can print it. ~150 video miscellaneous video files up to about 2GB each is similarly instantaneous.

Comment: More tests show that is problem must be a problem with the raspbian OS running on my raspberry Pi 3 B.  I would have never guessed that the OS would be the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same need as you and solved it with a workaround.

Instead of checking if $file is a directory, I checked if the file $file.'\..' exists.

This second approach is much faster (empirical testing at least).

So your code can be rewritten like this:

```
$files = array();
$directory = opendir($dir);
while ($file = readdir($directory))
{
    if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != '$RECYCLE.BIN' && file_exists($directory.'\\'.$file.'\\..') )
    {
        // do things...
    }
}
closedir($directory);
```